# screen scraping a coldfusion page with login screen

Tags: coldfusion, screen-scraping

I need to screen scrape ( with permission) and intranet website and extract data from the page. This is a cfm application with a login. The user needs to login, make a selection from the dropdown, click on a link and then arrive at the page which needs to be scraped. 
I know using cfhttp method = get, will get the contents from the remote url. but how do i handle the login part? and automating the click on the dropdown and click on all the links. 
please advice on what can be used to achieve this? TIA

Comment: What exact problem are you having with the login part?  Also, if the user arrives at a page, why does it need to be scraped?

Comment: The application doesnot belong to this group, and we want to scrape the data and load it into our database and pull on our application. The source cfm application owner is not willing to give the db access.

Comment: The problem is that the `cfhttp` request is being made by the ColdFusion server NOT the logged in user. Hence, why you are having issues with the login.

Comment: So they're willing for you to scrape it but unwilling to give database access? :/ You could maybe use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to do the UI side - it can then open browser windows to send the data to a CF webservice for storing/manipulating it, but really I'd be bugging them just to give you db access or at least a data export.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have the login part working. The are not ready to give the access to the db :(. So i need to screen scrape this page which has a tabular data and save it to a text file. Which will then be loaded into the DB.

Comment: Have they given a reason why they are not willing to grant DB access? if they are afraid of losing data, they can create a user account that  has 'read only' access.

Comment: All has been tried to gain the read only access. They are getting their data also as feeds from different other applications. It would be the easiest method out to get the data but it is not the case here!

Comment: The server technology (coldfusion) isn't a factor here. You can scrape them with any programming language that has a decent forms library. Some people also like phantonjs, selenium, visual web ripper, mozenda. There's really dozens of options.

Comment: Its been 5 years, wish you would have shared how you got the login part working.